# Usage Parallel from System.Threading.Tasks

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

Studing parallel computing in PowerShell I read a lot of *-Job cmdlets, ForEach-Parallel and etc. But I cannot find any information about usage of System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel in PowerShell. It seems that Parallel requires IEnumerable and generic delegate (Action), something like this:

```
 [System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel]::ForEach( [string[]]$data, [Action[string]]{param($str) <# do something #> } )
```

But PowerShell grobles that command cannot run outside a runspace. So I looking for a correct way to use Parallel in PowerShell. Any suggestions? Should I create a runspace in a manner as it requires *-Job cmdlets?

Comment: I looked into this a long time ago and found this blog post: http://www.get-blog.com/?p=189

Comment: @Kate Page You can use [Workflows with parallel activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_parallel?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @veefu Yeah, I already read that blogpost, it's interesring but it doesn't about Parallel type.

Comment: @Manu Yes, I can. But I asked about Parallel type.

Comment: @KatePage The short answer is `Parallel.ForEach()` is not suitable for powershell execution, because there's no way for the Action parameter to be assigned a runspace - the `Parallel` type has "no clue" about runspaces and powershell so to say.